# Preprocessor macro concatenation strings with dots

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, string-concatenation

I am trying to write macros set_DIR(), clr_DIR(), etc. in a library for microcontrollers from family AVR16-AVR128.

I have problem wiht adding letter V to port names in a macro.

In code below I described when is a place, where preprocessor should add letter V if virtual ports are enabled.

I can't use functions. Virtual ports changes bits in ports in 1 cycle of CPU clock, and I need it. So I must use macros to generate fastest code.

```
//=== From  microcontroller toolchain header: ioavr128db64.h  =========

/* Virtual Ports */
typedef struct VPORT_struct
{
    register8_t DIR;
    register8_t OUT;
    register8_t IN;
    register8_t INTFLAGS;
} VPORT_t;

#define VPORTA      (*(VPORT_t *) 0x0000)
#define VPORTB      (*(VPORT_t *) 0x0004)
#define VPORTC      (*(VPORT_t *) 0x0008)
// ... etc.

//--- PORTS definitions  (normal ports) -----

typedef struct PORT_struct
{
    register8_t DIRSET;
    register8_t DIRCLR;
    // etc.
} PORT_t;

#define PORTA       (*(PORT_t *) 0x0400)
#define PORTB       (*(PORT_t *) 0x0420)
#define PORTC       (*(PORT_t *) 0x0440)
// ... etc.


//==========  My definitions  ==================================


/* chceck if virtual ports are available */
// Caution! VVV is place where preprocessor should add letter V to choosen port
#ifdef VPORTA
    #define VPORTS  1
    #define set_DIR(x, y) VVV(x).DIR |= (y)     /* should generate: VPORTA.DIR |=  3 */
    #define clr_DIR(x, y) VVV(x).DIR &=~(y)     /* should generate: VPORTA.DIR &=~ 3 */
    /* etc. */
#else
    #define VPORTS  0
    #define set_DIR(x, y) (x).DIRSET = (y)      /* should generate: PORTA.DIRSET = 3 */
    #define clr_DIR(x, y) (x).DIRCLR = (y)      /* should generate: PORTA.DIRCLR = 3 */
    /* etc. */
#endif

//Caution! Its very important - must be like this!
#define PORT PORTA  /* may be chanched e.g. PORTC */

int main(void) 
{
    //example
    set_DIR(PORT, 3);
  
    return 0;
}
```

When I place where are VVV i pasted one letter V an error occurs:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Warning     implicit declaration of function 'V' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]  tests   main.c  11
```

How can fix it?

Comment: Why are you using token concatenation for this? Why not something like `#define set_DIR(x, y) (x).DIR |= (y)`?

Comment: 99% of the time when you get an error saying that token pasting is invalid, it actually means you don't need to use token pasting at all.

Comment: Thank you for answare.
Code above is only pice of that i want to do.

In some microcontrollers there are virtual ports, but in others none.
So sometimes i need
VPORTA.DIR |= 3
and sometimes I need that 
PORTA.DIR |= 3
(letter V at the n begining in name of register).

/* chceck if virtual ports are available */
#ifdef VPORTA
 #define VPORTS 1
 #define set_DIR(x, y) V(x).DIR |= (y)
#else
 #define VPORTS 0
 #define set_DIR(x, y) (x).DIRSET = (y)
#endif

This (with letter V) dont work:  #define set_DIR(x, y) V(x).DIR |= (y)

Comment: You need to paste V and PORTA together, and that actually requires token pasting. You snippet in the question is pasting in the wrong place.

Comment: Did I posted in correct place now?

Comment: I did't mean you "posted" in the wrong place. I meant you "pasted" (applied the "##" operator) in the wrong place. You want to concat "V" and "PORTS" together using "##", not something and dot together. You should not post that as an answer because it is not one, I suggest you delete that answer.

Comment: Of course if all you need is conditionally using "VPORTA" vs "PORTA", you don't need token-pasting at all, a simple `#if` is enough. I was suggesting on the assumption that you need  "V" on other ports as well, for example you also need "VPORTB", "VPORTC". In that case you should use "##" to concatenate the prefix and the port together, i.e. `V ## x`, but that has nothing to do with the dot after it. So you shouldn't do `V ## x ## .`. I hope it's clear this time.

Comment: Do not edit a question to change change it or add a new question, particularly after answers have been posted. To ask a new question, post a separate new question.

Comment: I edited question again after yours answers :( I'm sorry for the confusion. I'm just learning to use it stackoverflow.

Comment: For your newest update, if you must use macros, you just do `#define set_DIR(x, y) set_DIR_impl(x,y)`, and `#define set_DIR_impl(x,y) (V##x).DIR |= (y)`. Note that since someone has posted an answer you should not edit the question to something that invalidates existing answers. This is not allowed on SO and you should ask a new question instead.

Comment: @WeijunZhou Unfortunately #define set_DIR_impl(x,y) (V##x).DIR |= (y) generate error and warning.  Error pasting "V" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
Warning implicit declaration of function 'V'

Comment: I didn't test it because I was on mobile. See the answer by ad absurdum for the corrected version based on the same idea.

Answer (score 3):

If you must use a macro for this, it seems like you will need to introduce some indirection to accomplish the token concatenation. Here is a collection of three macros that do what it is that I think you are asking:

```
#define XX_set_DIR(x, y) ((x).DIR |= (y))
#define X_set_DIR(x, y) XX_set_DIR(V ## x, y)
#define set_DIR(x, y) X_set_DIR(x, y)
```

Given `#define VPORTA (*(VPORT_t *) 0x0000)`, `#define PORT PORTA` and the macro invocation `set_DIR(PORT, 3);` as suggested in the OP question, this expands to `(((*(VPORT_t *) 0x0000)).DIR |= (3));`.

The `set_DIR` macro takes the arguments `PORT` and `3` and expands `PORT` to `PORTA` (from the `#define` for `PORT`) before calling the `X_set_DIR` macro with `PORTA` and `3`. The `X_set_DIR` macro concatenates the tokens `V` and `PORTA` before calling the `XX_set_DIR` macro with the arguments `VPORTA` and `3`. Finally, the `XX_set_DIR` macro expands to code that accesses the `DIR` field of the struct indicated by the `#define` for `VPORTA`, i.e., the final expansion is `(((*(VPORT_t *) 0x0000)).DIR |= (3));`.

### Update

When I tested the above code I had defined `VPORTA`, but not `PORTA`. After a [comment from @KamilCuk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77736656/preprocessor-macro-concatenation-strings-with-dots/77738186#comment137049876_77738186) I found that including the definition for `PORTA` interfered with the expansion of the `set_DIR` macro.

After further review, it seems that OP desired solution is misguided in general. Aside from the advisability of using macros for this in the first place ([@gulpr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77736995/6879826)), the OP selection mechanism for virtual vs. normal ports makes no sense.

In particular, OP code has `#ifdef VPORTA`. This makes no sense as a selection mechanism because the toolchain header file already has defined `VPORTA`. OP will need to find another way to indicate whether a virtual port or a normal port is in use.

The simplest thing to do is to set `PORT` to the desired port like this:

```
/* From toolchain header file */
#define VPORTA      (*(VPORT_t *) 0x0000)
#define VPORTB      (*(VPORT_t *) 0x0004)
#define VPORTC      (*(VPORT_t *) 0x0008)

#define PORTA       (*(PORT_t *) 0x0400)
#define PORTB       (*(PORT_t *) 0x0420)
#define PORTC       (*(PORT_t *) 0x0440)

/* Port selection mechanism.
 * Select from:
 * PORTA, PORTB, PORTC,
 * VPORTA, VPORTB, VPORTC
*/
#define PORT VPORTA  

#define set_DIR(x, y) ((x).DIR |= (y))
// etc.

int main(void) 
{
    set_DIR(PORT, 3);
    return 0;
}
```

If OP requires a mechanism to toggle between virtual and normal ports a `#define` for specifically indicating whether a port is virtual or normal can be used:

```
/* From toolchain header file */
#define VPORTA      (*(VPORT_t *) 0x0000)
#define VPORTB      (*(VPORT_t *) 0x0004)
#define VPORTC      (*(VPORT_t *) 0x0008)

#define PORTA       (*(PORT_t *) 0x0400)
#define PORTB       (*(PORT_t *) 0x0420)
#define PORTC       (*(PORT_t *) 0x0440)

/* Port selection mechanism. */
#define PORT A   // Select: A, B, C
#define VIRTUAL  // Enable this for virtual ports; comment out for normal ports

#define XX_set_DIR(x, y) ((x).DIR |= (y))
// etc.

#ifdef VIRTUAL
    #define X_set_DIR(x, y) XX_set_DIR(VPORT ## x, y)
    // etc.
#else
    #define X_set_DIR(x, y) XX_set_DIR(PORT ## x, y)
    // etc.
#endif

#define set_DIR(x, y) X_set_DIR(x, y)
// etc.

int main(void) 
{
    set_DIR(PORT, 3);
    return 0;
}
```

[Here is a link to the Godbolt Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/Y7rPbqvf8) showing the expansion of the above macros. It works (for now) but this is a solution that is begging for problems. If `A` or `B` or any of the other port selector tokens is defined somewhere else this will probably not work as expected.

If you are going to use a macro for this, just use the simple approach and define `PORT` to the specific port that you want. But you might reconsider whether this needs to be a macro at all. No matter what you do, the actual access to the port structs will happen at runtime. Any performance gains that you get from macros will be minimal for the cost of all the problems that accompany using macros.

Comment: I do not think that will work.  `Given #define VPORTA (*(VPORT_t *) 0x0000)` Did you also `#define PORTA (*(PORT_t *) 0x0400)`? Could you post full code you tested with? I copied your code with PORTA and VPORTA definitions. https://godbolt.org/z/dEdanEo6E . The result of expansion is just `(VPORT).DIR` , and the "A" part is never added.

Comment: @KamilCuk -- yes, I failed to define `PORTA` in my original test code, and including this define interfered with the macro expansion.

Answer (score 2):

1. Avoid!!! Do not use those macros at all. Use **functions** and trust your compiler
2. Do not dereference those pointers in macros
3. If it is a hardware register you need to make it `volatile` as you want to work on the **actual** value stored in the register (which may be changed by hardware or async code), not on the value stored in the processor register.

```
#if defined(__GNUC__)
#define ALWAYSINLINE __attribute__((always_inline))
#else   //you can add here compiler specific stuff in similar macros
#define ALWAYSINLINE
#endif

typedef struct VPORT_struct
{
    volatile uint8_t DIR;
    volatile uint8_t OUT;
    volatile uint8_t IN;
    volatile uint8_t INTFLAGS;
} VPORT_t;

#define VPORTA      ((VPORT_t *) 0x0000)
#define VPORTB      ((VPORT_t *) 0x0004)
#define VPORTC      ((VPORT_t *) 0x0008)

inline static void ALWAYSINLINE set_DIR(VPORT_t *x, const uint8_t y) 
{
    x -> DIR |= y;
}

void foo(void)
{
    set_DIR(VPORTA, 3);
}
```

example generated code:

ARM:

```
        movs    r2, #0
        movs    r3, #3
        ldrb    r1, [r2]
        orrs    r3, r1
        strb    r3, [r2]
        bx      lr
```

AVR:

```
       ldi r30,0
        ldi r31,0
        ld r24,Z
        ori r24,lo8(3)
        st Z,r24
        ret
```

https://godbolt.org/z/jbKaaPGWE

## EDIT

```
#define PORT VPORTA

void bar(void)
{
    set_DIR(PORT, 3);
}

VPORT_t *ports[] = {VPORTA, VPORTB, VPORTC, NULL};

void setPortsDIR(VPORT_t *ports, uint8_t dir)
{
    for(VPORT_t *port = ports; port; port++)
    {
        set_DIR(port, dir);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm sorry but of course there are register in oryginal header of microcontroller library. I modified my question after answers but still have problem discribed there. In code i wrote cautions so  set_DIR(VPORTA, 3) not acceptable.

Comment: @DonduJacek it does not matter in function. you can user your `#define PORT VPORTA` you can use variables etc.

Comment: Sorry, but I cant use funnctions. Virtual ports changes bits in ports in 1 cycle of CPU clock. and i need it. So i must use macros to generate fastest code.

Comment: @DonduJacek " Virtual ports changes bits in ports in 1 cycle of CPU clock"* no they are not because you use `|` operator. It will never happen on any RMW architecture. Also the generated code for the inline function if you pass constant expression will be exactly the same (there is no function call). I think you need to understand a bit more how things work

Comment: Additionally, `VPORTA` could just be `static VPORT_t *const VPORTA = (VPORT_t *) 0x0000;` (btw, that's a null pointer) `Virtual ports changes bits in ports in 1 cycle of CPU clock` What compiler and architecture and compiler options are you using? How have you checked that?

Comment: @gulpr
You are wrong. In AVR128DB64 microcontrollers they are special registers to fast pin operations  - you can check it in documentation, see Virtual Ports: "The Virtual PORT registers map the most frequently used regular PORT registers into the I/O Register space with
single-cycle bit access.". But please it is not time to talk about it, i need make macro. Help me pls.

Comment: @KamilCuk It's GCC from Microchip Toolchain avr-gcc.exe (AVR_8_bit_GNU_Toolchain_3.7.0_1796) 7.3.0

Comment: There is no AVT gcc 7.3.0 on godbold, but there is 5.4.0.  The generated assembly using function posted in this answer, and using `VPORTA->DIR |= 3` is exactly the same. https://godbolt.org/z/M3dWvjbnb . There is no reason to use macros. `they are special registers to fast pin operations` While that is true, _how do you know_ your compiler is using them? Your compiler is not using them anyway. I would suspect, you would have to write `__asm__` code and use `SBR`  instructions yourself. Which _still_ is better done with no macros.

Comment: Have you _profiled_ that you actually care about that optimization? Why do you care? Still, let's say `VPORTA->DIR |= 1` could potentially be replaced by a single `SBR` instead of 6 instructions using `ORI`. That is an increase of 5 instructions. Even with AVR128DB64 running at 32kHz (which is insanely slow), 5 instructions that's 150us. Are 150 _micro_ seconds really worth optimizing for you? Why do you care about such speed? And anyway, if you care, _how do you know_ that using macros will be using SBR instruction? Have you inspected the assembly code to see it's there?

Comment: @KamilCuk your example is broken because you're using `3`, which has *two bits* set (so it won't use a single set-bit instruction), and because you're lacking an appropriate `-mmcu`. https://godbolt.org/z/fEqMj9n8E shows a working example.

Comment: @gulpr It's AVR. It has specific set/clear bit instructions for I/O ports. And yes, avr-gcc knows how to use them.

Comment: @hobbs Right -mmcu!  Note that OP in original code also used `3`, not `1<<3`. Still, the optimization, inlining, and not using macro arguments stand anyway.

Comment: @KamilCuk fair, that's a bug (an unrelated one, though). Should be using `_BV` either at the callsite or in the function.

Comment: @KamilCuk fine, I'm just trying to clear away all of the "it won't even work anyway!" which has now spread to basically *all* of the answers on this question.

Comment: I added a new answer in this topic about 1-cycles operations on my microcontroller.

Answer (score 1):

Change `#define set_DIR(x, y) x ## .DIR |= ## y` to `#define set_DIR(x, y) ((x).DIR |= (y))`.

> First: Code above generated error didn't convert PORT to VPORTA.

In macro processing, `##` is processed before the result is rescanned for further macro replacement, so `PORT` was combined with another token before it could be replaced by `VPORTA`. When the `##` are removed, that is not an issue.

> Second: Join with dot generate error.

Parsing expressions is part of the main C processing. It is not part of preprocessing, including macro replacement, and you should not try to use the `##` operator for that. `##` is for combining grammatical tokens.

In macros, you mostly simply write C code as if the macro parameters were ordinary identifiers, except they should often be parenthesized so that, when the argument is an expression with operators, it is taken as a single item in parentheses in the code resulting from macro expansion.

Comment: Parens around `(x).DIR |= (y)` would be best

Comment: You don't need two levels of macros if you removed `##`, I think. I'd also wrap the whole thing in `(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> #define set_DIR(x, y) VVV(x).DIR |= (y)     /* should generate: VPORTA.DIR |=  3 */
>
> #define PORTA       (*(PORT_t *) 0x0400)
>
> #define PORT PORTA  /* may be chanched e.g. PORTC */
>
> set_DIR(PORT, 3);
> ```

It is impossible to achieve. It is not possible to partially expand a macro. `PORT` in the argument of `set_DIR(PORT` is **either** not expanded at all, in which case it stays to be `PORT`, or is fully expanded to `(*(PORT_t *) 0x0400)`. It is not possible to "partially" expand a macro first to `PORT -> PORTA` to then add a `V` character.

*Strongly* consider using functions as presented in the other great answer.

The simplest there is, just pick a different unique PORT names for your transformations, where you define your own ports.

```
#define PORTA       (*(PORT_t *) 0x0400)
#define VPORTA      (*(VPORT_t *) 0x0000)

#ifdef VPORTA
// map MYPORT to VPORT
#define MYPORTA  VPORTA
#define set_DIR(x, y) (x).DIR |= (y)
#else
// map MYPORT to PORT
#define MYPORTA  PORTA
#define set_DIR(x, y) (x).DIRSET |= (y)
#endif

#define PORT  MYPORTA

set_DIR(PORT, 3); // -> ((*(VPORT_t *) 0x0000)).DIR |= (3);
```

Comment: "It is not possible to 'partially' expand a macro first to PORT -> PORTA to then add a V character." OK it's excplain everything for me. Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Because in this topic there is additional discusion about virtual ports i decided to show that avr-gcc compiler:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Atmel\Studio\7.0\toolchain\avr8\avr8-gnu-toolchain\bin>avr-gcc.exe --version
avr-gcc.exe (AVR_8_bit_GNU_Toolchain_3.7.0_1796) 7.3.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
```

can use 1-cycle assembler instructions when using bitwise operations on pins for some AVR familly microcontrollers like AVR128DB64:

```
int main(void)
{
    VPORTA.DIR  |= (1<<0);
    VPORTA.DIR  |= (1<<1);
    VPORTA.DIR  |= (1<<2);

    while(1)
    {
        VPORTA.OUT    |=  (1<<0);    //Set pin PA0 to high
        VPORTA.OUT    &=~ (1<<0);    //Set pin PA0 to low
        VPORTA.OUT    |=  (1<<1);    //Set pin PA1 to high
        VPORTA.OUT    &=~ (1<<1);    //Set pin PA1 to low
        VPORTA.OUT    |=  (1<<2);    //Set pin PA2 to high
        VPORTA.OUT    &=~ (1<<2);    //Set pin PA2 to low
    }
}
```

result:

```
int main(void)
{
    VPORTA.DIR  |= (1<<0);
 11c:   00 9a           sbi 0x00, 0 ; 0
    VPORTA.DIR  |= (1<<1);
 11e:   01 9a           sbi 0x00, 1 ; 0
    VPORTA.DIR  |= (1<<2);
 120:   02 9a           sbi 0x00, 2 ; 0

    while(1)
    {
        VPORTA.OUT    |=  (1<<0);    //Set pin PA0 to high
 122:   08 9a           sbi 0x01, 0 ; 1
        VPORTA.OUT    &=~ (1<<0);    //Set pin PA0 to low
 124:   08 98           cbi 0x01, 0 ; 1
        VPORTA.OUT    |=  (1<<1);    //Set pin PA1 to high
 126:   09 9a           sbi 0x01, 1 ; 1
        VPORTA.OUT    &=~ (1<<1);    //Set pin PA1 to low
 128:   09 98           cbi 0x01, 1 ; 1
        VPORTA.OUT    |=  (1<<2);    //Set pin PA2 to high
 12a:   0a 9a           sbi 0x01, 2 ; 1
        VPORTA.OUT    &=~ (1<<2);    //Set pin PA2 to low
 12c:   0a 98           cbi 0x01, 2 ; 1
 12e:   f9 cf           rjmp    .-14        ; 0x122 <main+0x6>
```

In datasheet:

```
Virtual Ports
The Virtual PORT registers map the most frequently used regular PORT registers into the I/O Register space with
single-cycle bit access. Access to the Virtual PORT registers has the same outcome as access to the regular
registers but allows for memory-specific instructions, such as bit manipulation instructions, which cannot be used in
the extended I/O Register space where the regular PORT registers reside.
```